# PrestaShop 1.3.1 sorting products only in current page

Tags: php, sorting, prestashop

Dear Colleagues,

I have a problem with sorting by price in prestashop 1.3.1.
When i choose sort from “the lowest price” or or sort from  “highest price”, it´s work but only in current page.
This is very irritating bug and I do not know how to fix it.
I learned that this error is difficult to fix and it was resolved in in 1.4 version but i can not upgrade my presta shop from 1.3.1 to 1.4.
Can anyone know how to fix it or give me some directions?

Your prompt will be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I dont use PS 1.3 for a long time but I'll try to answer you...

If you want to keep the sorting between pages, you must change the links in the pagination to add order parameters.

In your file "/themes/[your-theme]/pagination.tpl", edit the links by replace "$link->goPage()" by right links. Look into "product-sort.tpl" for inspiration.

Try to call these links manually before trying to change them, I'm not sure if the order will be kept and I cannot test it for you now.